# RocketRaid 642L Drivers

Tags: release-freya

I am having a bit of a hard time getting the drivers for my rocketraid 642L controller to work on here (shortly after fixing all the graphics card driver issues..) After installing the drivers and turning on my enclosure it will no longer boot. However, booting with the enclosures off will.

Log:

```
Aug 16 23:13:46 ares kernel: [  322.929671] rr640l:RocketRAID 640L/642L/644L/RR644LS SATA controller driver v1.3.9
Aug 16 23:13:47 ares kernel: [  323.350828] rr640l:adapter at PCI 9:0:0, IRQ 99
Aug 16 23:13:48 ares kernel: [  323.574289] rr640l:[0 0  ] start port.
Aug 16 23:13:48 ares kernel: [  323.574290] rr640l:[0 0  ] start port hard reset (probe 1).
Aug 16 23:13:48 ares kernel: [  323.772517] rr640l:[0 1  ] start port.
Aug 16 23:13:48 ares kernel: [  323.772518] rr640l:[0 1  ] start port hard reset (probe 1).
Aug 16 23:13:48 ares kernel: [  323.970746] rr640l:[0 2  ] start port.
Aug 16 23:13:48 ares kernel: [  323.970746] rr640l:[0 2  ] start port hard reset (probe 1).
Aug 16 23:13:48 ares kernel: [  324.168973] rr640l:[0 3  ] start port.
Aug 16 23:13:48 ares kernel: [  324.168973] rr640l:[0 3  ] start port hard reset (probe 1).
Aug 16 23:13:51 ares kernel: [  326.774267] rr640l:[0 0  ] start port soft reset (probe 1).
Aug 16 23:13:51 ares kernel: [  327.421629] rr640l:[0 1  ] start port soft reset (probe 1).
Aug 16 23:13:52 ares kernel: [  328.244796] rr640l:[0 0  ] pmp attached: vendor 0x1b4b device 0x9715.
Aug 16 23:13:52 ares kernel: [  328.244799] rr640l:[0 2  ] failed to hard reset.
Aug 16 23:13:52 ares kernel: [  328.244804] rr640l:[0 2  ] failed to perform port hard reset.
Aug 16 23:13:52 ares kernel: [  328.268781] rr640l:[0 1  ] pmp attached: vendor 0x1b4b device 0x9715.
Aug 16 23:13:52 ares kernel: [  328.444615] rr640l:[0 3  ] failed to hard reset.
Aug 16 23:13:52 ares kernel: [  328.444621] rr640l:[0 3  ] failed to perform port hard reset.
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469674] ata12.00: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469676] ata12.01: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469677] ata12.02: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469677] ata12.03: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469678] ata12.04: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469680] ata12.15: exception Emask 0x4 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469682] ata12.00: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469683] ata12.00: failed command: CHECK POWER MODE
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469685] ata12.00: cmd e5/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 23
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469685]          res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469686] ata12.00: status: { DRDY }
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469687] ata12.01: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469688] ata12.01: failed command: CHECK POWER MODE
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469690] ata12.01: cmd e5/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 24
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469690]          res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469690] ata12.01: status: { DRDY }
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469691] ata12.02: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469692] ata12.03: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469693] ata12.04: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.469695] ata12.15: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557576] ata11.00: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557578] ata11.01: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557579] ata11.02: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557579] ata11.03: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557580] ata11.04: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557582] ata11.15: exception Emask 0x4 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557583] ata11.00: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557584] ata11.00: failed command: CHECK POWER MODE
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557586] ata11.00: cmd e5/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 15
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557586]          res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557587] ata11.00: status: { DRDY }
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557588] ata11.01: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557589] ata11.01: failed command: CHECK POWER MODE
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557590] ata11.01: cmd e5/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 14
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557590]          res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557591] ata11.01: status: { DRDY }
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557592] ata11.02: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557593] ata11.03: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557594] ata11.04: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.557595] ata11.15: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.562127] rr640l:[0 1  ] port handle error (irq status 00400000)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.562129] rr640l:[0 1  ] target phy rdy changed
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.997147] ata12.15: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Aug 16 23:13:55 ares kernel: [  331.997151] ata12.15: PMP revalidation failed (errno=-19)
Aug 16 23:13:59 ares kernel: [  334.671516] rr640l:[0 0 0] start device soft reset.
Aug 16 23:13:59 ares kernel: [  335.319028] rr640l:[0 1 0] start device soft reset.
Aug 16 23:13:59 ares kernel: [  336.017206] rr640l:[0 0 0] config_device path_id :0 
Aug 16 23:13:59 ares kernel: [  336.030144] rr640l:[0 0  ] port started successfully.
Aug 16 23:13:59 ares kernel: [  336.030146] rr640l:[0 0 0] device probed successfully.
Aug 16 23:13:59 ares kernel: [  336.048860] rr640l:Backup stamp 5261775f sum 0 backed 1
Aug 16 23:13:59 ares kernel: [  336.059788] rr640l:Master stamp 5261775f sum 0 backed 1
Aug 16 23:13:59 ares kernel: [  336.059790] rr640l:raw ffff88078594b038 bad_sector 0
Aug 16 23:14:00 ares kernel: [  336.081127] rr640l:[0 1 0] config_device path_id :1 
Aug 16 23:14:00 ares kernel: [  336.094064] rr640l:[0 1  ] port started successfully.
Aug 16 23:14:00 ares kernel: [  336.094065] rr640l:[0 1 0] device probed successfully.
Aug 16 23:14:00 ares kernel: [  336.105829] rr640l:Backup stamp 5261775f sum 0 backed 1
Aug 16 23:14:00 ares kernel: [  336.111791] rr640l:Master stamp 5261775f sum 0 backed 1
Aug 16 23:14:00 ares kernel: [  336.111792] rr640l:raw ffff88078594a838 bad_sector 0
Aug 16 23:14:00 ares kernel: [  336.115834] scsi19 : rr640l
Aug 16 23:14:00 ares kernel: [  336.992285] ata12.15: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:14:00 ares kernel: [  336.992335] ata11.15: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Aug 16 23:14:00 ares kernel: [  336.992343] ata11.15: PMP revalidation failed (errno=-19)
Aug 16 23:14:05 ares kernel: [  341.987385] ata11.15: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:14:06 ares kernel: [  342.470901] ata12.15: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Aug 16 23:14:06 ares kernel: [  342.470905] ata12.15: PMP revalidation failed (errno=-19)
Aug 16 23:14:06 ares kernel: [  342.470907] ata12.15: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
Aug 16 23:14:11 ares kernel: [  347.466004] ata12.15: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:14:11 ares kernel: [  347.466021] ata11.15: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Aug 16 23:14:11 ares kernel: [  347.466024] ata11.15: PMP revalidation failed (errno=-19)
Aug 16 23:14:11 ares kernel: [  347.466026] ata11.15: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
Aug 16 23:14:16 ares kernel: [  352.461169] ata11.15: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:14:16 ares kernel: [  352.944675] ata12.15: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
Aug 16 23:14:16 ares kernel: [  352.944683] ata12.15: PMP revalidation failed (errno=-19)
Aug 16 23:14:16 ares kernel: [  352.944686] ata12.15: failed to recover PMP after 5 tries, giving up
Aug 16 23:14:16 ares kernel: [  352.944689] ata12.15: Port Multiplier detaching
Aug 16 23:14:16 ares kernel: [  352.944695] ahci 0000:09:00.0: FBS is disabled
Aug 16 23:14:16 ares kernel: [  352.944700] ata12.00: disabled
Aug 16 23:14:16 ares kernel: [  352.944702] ata12.01: disabled
Aug 16 23:14:16 ares kernel: [  352.944705] ata12.00: disabled
Aug 16 23:14:21 ares kernel: [  357.939785] ata12: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:14:21 ares kernel: [  357.939837] ata11.15: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
Aug 16 23:14:21 ares kernel: [  357.939845] ata11.15: PMP revalidation failed (errno=-19)
Aug 16 23:14:21 ares kernel: [  357.939848] ata11.15: failed to recover PMP after 5 tries, giving up
Aug 16 23:14:21 ares kernel: [  357.939850] ata11.15: Port Multiplier detaching
Aug 16 23:14:21 ares kernel: [  357.939857] ahci 0000:09:00.0: FBS is disabled
Aug 16 23:14:21 ares kernel: [  357.939861] ata11.00: disabled
Aug 16 23:14:21 ares kernel: [  357.939864] ata11.01: disabled
Aug 16 23:14:21 ares kernel: [  357.939867] ata11.00: disabled
Aug 16 23:14:26 ares kernel: [  362.934898] ata11: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:14:27 ares kernel: [  363.418431] ata12: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Aug 16 23:14:27 ares kernel: [  363.426395] ata11: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Aug 16 23:14:32 ares kernel: [  368.413540] ata12.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
Aug 16 23:14:32 ares kernel: [  368.413550] ata12.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
Aug 16 23:14:32 ares kernel: [  368.413555] ata12: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:14:32 ares kernel: [  368.421533] ata11.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
Aug 16 23:14:32 ares kernel: [  368.421542] ata11.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
Aug 16 23:14:32 ares kernel: [  368.421546] ata11: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:14:32 ares kernel: [  368.905034] ata12: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Aug 16 23:14:32 ares kernel: [  368.913027] ata11: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Aug 16 23:14:42 ares kernel: [  378.895256] ata12.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
Aug 16 23:14:42 ares kernel: [  378.895262] ata12.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
Aug 16 23:14:42 ares kernel: [  378.895263] ata12: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
Aug 16 23:14:42 ares kernel: [  378.895265] ata12: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:14:42 ares kernel: [  378.903251] ata11.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
Aug 16 23:14:42 ares kernel: [  378.903256] ata11.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
Aug 16 23:14:42 ares kernel: [  378.903258] ata11: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
Aug 16 23:14:42 ares kernel: [  378.903259] ata11: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:14:43 ares kernel: [  379.386776] ata12: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
Aug 16 23:14:43 ares kernel: [  379.394771] ata11: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.357474] ata12.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.357480] ata12.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.357483] ata12: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.365440] ata11.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.365445] ata11.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.365446] ata11: hard resetting link
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.848968] ata12: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.848982] ata12: EH complete
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.848986] ata12.00: detaching (SCSI 11:0:0:0)
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849186] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdi] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849199] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdi]  
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849201] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849202] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdi] Stopping disk
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849205] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdi] START_STOP FAILED
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849206] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdi]  
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849207] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849243] ata12.01: detaching (SCSI 11:1:0:0)
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849469] sd 11:1:0:0: [sdj] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849481] sd 11:1:0:0: [sdj]  
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849482] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849483] sd 11:1:0:0: [sdj] Stopping disk
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849486] sd 11:1:0:0: [sdj] START_STOP FAILED
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849487] sd 11:1:0:0: [sdj]  
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.849488] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.856945] ata11: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.856959] ata11: EH complete
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.856963] ata11.00: detaching (SCSI 10:0:0:0)
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857159] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857170] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg]  
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857170] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857171] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] Stopping disk
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857173] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] START_STOP FAILED
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857174] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg]  
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857175] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857211] ata11.01: detaching (SCSI 10:1:0:0)
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857751] sd 10:1:0:0: [sdh] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857764] sd 10:1:0:0: [sdh]  
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857765] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857766] sd 10:1:0:0: [sdh] Stopping disk
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857769] sd 10:1:0:0: [sdh] START_STOP FAILED
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857770] sd 10:1:0:0: [sdh]  
Aug 16 23:15:13 ares kernel: [  409.857770] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

**Edit 1**

So after upgrading the kernel to 3.19.0-26 I was able to boot with the raid array on, the drivers technically uninstalled, and see the disks themselves in my os. However, it is not recognizing that they are in a raid array. How would I further diagnose this?